# How to set ChartJS Axis label with PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, chart.js

I'm using PrimeFaces 7 that comes with ChartJS.

There's options to add title/label to the chart itself and also to the datasets. However, I couldn't find a way to add titles/labels to the axes. Also there's no examples on how to do that on the showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartjs/

I tried using the extender function, much like we did with the old JQPlot in the older versions of PF. So on the JS function, I'm trying to configure the label as shown here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html

So it's looking like this:

xhtml:

```
<script>

        function extender() {

                if (!this.cfg.config.options) {
                    this.cfg.config.options = {}
                }

               var options = $.extend(true, {}, this.cfg.config.options);

               options = {
                      scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                          scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'test'
                          }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                          scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'test'
                          }
                        }],
                      }
                    };

               $.extend(true, this.cfg.config, options);
            };

</script>
```

Java Bean:

```
barModel = new BarChartModel();
barModel.setExtender("extender");
```

And: no labels are showing up.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You can specify to labels in Java code by BarChartModel also, did you try that or don't you want to don't this way for some reason?

Comment: I also tried setting Y Axis label on the bean:

                `BarChartOptions options = new BarChartOptions();
  CartesianScales scales = new CartesianScales();
  CartesianLinearAxes linearAxes = new CartesianLinearAxes();
  linearAxes.setId("left-y-axis");
  linearAxes.setPosition("left");
  CartesianScaleLabel label = new CartesianScaleLabel();
  label.setLabelString("test");
  linearAxes.setScaleLabel(label);
  scales.addYAxesData(linearAxes);
  options.setScales(scales);
                barModel.setOptions(options);`

But it also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My JS function was not correct. The below code is now working as intended: y axis label is being shown.

```
function extender1() {

               var options = {

               options: {
                      scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                          scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Order amount'
                          }
                        }],
                      }
                    }                  
            };
               $.extend(true, this.cfg.config, options);
        };
```